# implementation of directed graph with two edges per node - recursive search function

Tags: c++, debugging, data-structures, recursion

I've started playing with structures, I've created one which I've called `LR`:

```
struct LR{
    int v;
    LR* L;
    LR* R;
};
```

I understand how to manipulate it in generic way - code in `main` below, before I've started building class, I've started to write recursive function which takes "address" of node in LR in form of string ("LRLRR") and returns needed LR, but I still get errors from compiler :

```
LR.cpp In function 'LR chooseNode(LR*, std::string)':    
LR.cpp [Error] request for member 'L' in 'tree', which is of pointer type 'LR*'
```

`(maybe you meant to use '->' ?)` - error for line in part with recursion `chooseNode(*tree.L,str2);`

What am I doing wrong or rather how to debug it ? ( except the whole concept of my implementation which is rather excercise).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define SHOW(a) std::cout << #a << ": " << (a) << std::endl
using namespace std;
struct LR{
    int v;
    LR* L;
    LR* R;
};

LR chooseNode(LR* tree, string str){// for example str="LRL"    

            // for clarity I've cutted the most of the code

            if(str[0]=='L')
            chooseNode(*tree.L,str2);   
        else if(str[0]=='R')
            chooseNode(*tree.R,str2);

};


int main(){

    LR d1,d2,d3;
    d1.v=4; 
    d1.L=&d2;
    (*(d1.L)).L=&d3;
    d3.v=12345;
    SHOW((*(*d1.L).L).v);


    cout<<"Opis: "<<"\n";
    SHOW(int(&d1));
    SHOW(int(&d2));
    SHOW(sizeof(d2.v));

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Is ` string  str2[str.size()-1];` really meant to define an array of strings?

Comment: Also do you want `return chooseNode()`? Else you have a missing return value for those cases.

Comment: @Keith there is something more going on but I have different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

`tree` is a pointer of type `LR*`

Accessing struct members from a pointer can be done with this syntax:

```
tree->L
```

Or (far less commonly, but it looks like what you were attempting)

```
(*tree).L
```

> Or rather how to debug it ?

"Debugging" is a process done to a successfully built executable.  You have a compiler error, so debugging does not apply.

Comment: OP is returning an `LR` by value, so presumably it should be `*tree->L` (or `*(tree->L)` for clarity)...but maybe the return type should change instead

Comment: yes I've tried `chooseNode(tree->L,str2);` but compiler sees the error in the same place

Comment: @Qbik try `*tree->L`, which is the same as `*((*tree).L)`, but are you sure you want to return `LR` by value?

Comment: @Qbik not the same error, I'm sure.  What is the new error?

Comment: @DrewDormann I think it's the one I pointed out :D (it's pretty clear if you look at the return type)

Comment: @StephenLin I suspect that you're right but whatever the error is, Qbik should read it.

Comment: the problem was because I've tried *tree.R instead of (*tree).R and '.' is stronger then '*' :)

Answer (score 1):

@Qbik - got to thinking about your string handling and efficiency, and ended up with this, which I might as well share with you:

```
LR* chooseNodeUsingCString(LR* tree, const char* str){// for example str="LRL"
    // Pre-conditions
    if ((str[0] == 0) || (tree == 0))
        return 0; // or assert or whatever

    // This assumes an L unless an R, but handle however if needed.
    LR* next = tree->L;
    if (str[0]=='R')
        next = tree->R;

    // End of path case
    if (str[1] == 0)
    {
        return next;
    }

    // Error case, path string does not exist in the tree.
    if (!next)
        return 0;

    // Standard recurse case; easy iteration with no copying along a C-String.
    const char* pathStringWithFirstElementRemoved = str + 1;
    return chooseNodeUsingCString(next, pathStringWithFirstElementRemoved);
};
```